# Can the Samur Eye be Painted?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have a Samur Eye, I and don't know if I can paint it. The TF2 wiki does not help me. Can I paint it? If I can, what types of paint can be used (team paint, normal paint, ect, ect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The wiki states in the item's infobox](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Samur-Eye), and through the lack of painted images, that the Samur-Eye is not paintable.